# How to find parameter equations of the straight line with the vector equation

Tags: vectors, parametric

vector equation is $ x= -3e_2-4 e_3+t(e_1-e_2)$.

I am aware that the equation of a line is in the form of $R=R_0+tv$ but i am confused since my equation of the line seems to be in a different format. 
This is for study purposes so feel free to use other numbers if it makes it easier to explain.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $\vec e_i$ are the vectors of the standard basis ( as I suppose), than your equation:
$$
\vec x= -3 \vec{e_2}-4 \vec{e_3}+t(\vec{e_1}-\vec {e_2})
$$
is the same as:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\-3\\-4
\end{bmatrix}
+t\begin{bmatrix}
1\\-1\\0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
can you see this?

Comment: I believe I see the logic behind it now. parameter equations are x = 0+t, y= -3-t, z= -4. is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. We can write this equation in different forms, but it is always the same!